# Table to check all landscapes and clients in server

Tags: abap, sap-basis

There's any SAP table that shows all the landscapes (and respective clients) in a server?

I need a list with the Development, Quality and Production landscapes, and they respective clients to work with in a FM.

Comment: I found the table TMSCSYS, but it doesn't have the clients...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List of SAP clients can be obtained from [T000](https://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/tabl/t000.html) table. Don't know what do you mean under *landscapes* as SAP system is a part of only *one* landscape usually. It can be included in several landscapes but this configuration is rather unusual. More on this [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/63/a30a4ac00811d2851c0000e8a57770/content.htm).
I suppose you mean systems that form [Transport Domain](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/44/b4a1027acc11d1899e0000e829fbbd/frameset.htm), if so they are listed in `TMSCSYS` table.

Comment: T000 lists the clients of the current system, not those of any other systems in the same landscape.

Comment: Yes, clients of other systems are unavailable externally if you are a developer. You need [SolMan](https://blogs.sap.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/15_615506.png) for that, which is exclusively [Basis](http://ken-lori.com/datadisk/www.datadisk.co.uk.100314/html_docs/sap/basis/sol_manager.htm) tool.